# How to specify which application-{env}.yml to use in application.yml while using maven package? Is it specified in runtime or compile time?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, weblogic, maven-3

Have tried all methods.. passing a variable from maven pom.xml to application.yml file. using @environmentVariable@, -Dspring.profiles.active etc.

Comment: The `--spring.profiles.active` is something for runtime and **NOT** for build time.

Comment: I see.. I am trying to package a .war file to deploy into an app server. How do I select the specific application-{env}.yml file in this case?

Comment: The application server should have some kind of configuration for env variables etc.

Comment: Ok will try that out. But what if I dont have access to application server? i.e. i want to select the specific application-{env}.yml through jenkins?

Comment: In order to start the server with the WAR, there has to be a start script or a run command defined somewhere. That's where you would want to specify the active spring profile.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the yml file used by spring boot packaged as a war file, you should configure the `spring.config.additional-location` context parameter in your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, similar to this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.config.additional-location</param-name>
        <param-value>file:./my-application.yml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```